# How to use iptables to forward all data from an IP to a Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, iptables

OK, in an attempt to get some response, a TL;DR version. I know that the following command:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 --dport 80 --source 1.1.1.1 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

... will redirect all traffic from port 80 to port 8080. The problem is that I have to do this for every port that is to be redirected. To be future-proof, I want all ports for an IP to be redirected to a different (internal) IP, so that if one might decide to enable SSH, they can directly connect without worrying about iptables.

What is needed to reliable forward all traffic from an external IP, to an internal IP, and vice versa?

---

**Extended version**

I've scoured the internet for this, but I never got a solid answer. What I have is one physical server (HOST), with several virtual machines (VM) that need traffic redirected to them. Just getting it to work with a single machine is enough for now.

The VM's run under VirtualBox, and are set to use a host-only adapter (vboxnet0). Everything seems to work, but it is greatly lagging. Both the host (CentOS 5.6) and the guest (Ubuntu 10.04) machine are running Linux.

What I did was the following:

1. Configure the VM to have a static IP in the network of the vboxnet0 adapter.
2. Add an IP alias to the host, registering to the dedicated (outside) IP.
3. Setup iptables to allow traffic to come through (via sysctl).
4. Configure iptables to DNAT and SNAT data from a given IP address to the internal address.

iptables commands:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d $OUT_IP -I eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination $IN_IP
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s $IN_IP -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $OUT_IP
```

Now the site works, but is really, really slow. I'm hoping I missed something simple, but I'm out of ideas for now.

Some background info: before this, the site was working with basic port forwarding. E.g. port 80 was mapped to port 8080 using iptables. In VirtualBox (having the network adapter configured as NAT), a port forwarding the other way around made things work beautifully. The problem was twofold: first, multiple ports needed to be forwarded (for admin interfaces, https, ssh, etc). Second, it only allowed one IP address to use port 80.

To resolve things, multiple external IP addresses are used for different (sub)domains. Likewise, the "VirtualBox" network will contain the virtual machines:

```
DNS              Ext. IP    Adapter   VM            "VirtalBox" IP
------------------------------------------------------------------
a.example.com    1.1.1.1    eth0:1    vm_guest_1    192.168.56.1
b.example.com    2.2.2.2    eth0:2    vm_guest_2    192.168.56.2
c.example.com    3.3.3.3    eth0:3    vm_guest_3    192.168.56.3
```

And so on. Put simply, the goal is to channel all traffic from `a.example.com` to `vm_guest_1` (of put differently, from `1.1.1.1` to `192.168.56.1`). And achieve this with an acceptable speed :).

Answer (score 2):

Since you already allocate public addresses to your VMs, maybe you should consider bridged networking instead of NAT ? You'd get a much cleaner setup.

If you are worried about your guests interfering with each other in a bridged setup, you can still use `ebtables` and/or static arp to harden things.

Answer (score 1):

## Check current iptables rules

`iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

## Enable IP forwarding

`echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

## Rules to forward PG traffic

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination new-master-ip:80`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

## Check iptables rules

`iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).